# Shortest distance between two points on a sphere in a given direction

Tags: spheres, spherical-geometry

I am looking to calculate the shortest distance between two points on a sphere in a given direction. In other words, in the diagram [**here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw0wP.png) (altered from a Wikipedia article), I am looking for the shortest 'straight' line that connects Q and P  where we must always be travelling eastward on the sphere as well as the distance of the line. In other words, the distance we must travel from Q to P without crossing the green line.

Through my reading of spherical trigonometry, it seems that it exclusively uses geodesic lines which do not apply here. My understanding with non-Euclidean geometry is very limited, I am wondering if there is a formulation for this problem and also if there are methods for describing non-geodesic lines on the sphere. I am also unsure whether the line I have drawn on the sphere would be classified as 'straight' and whether there is a definition of a straight line in spherical geometry.

Comment: Perhaps [loxodromes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Loxodrome.html) or the [Mercator Projection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MercatorProjection.html) will be useful. Will investigate further. + Rhumb lines